# Getting keyboard events in headless environment

Tags: java, linux, keyboard, headless

My title basically tells my goal.  I would like to get some sort of keyboard input, be it an event or just plain text, using java in a headless environment.  I believe there is a file in /dev that registers all keyboard events, but i don't know exactly the file name, nor if there is any special encoding around the file to read from it.

Comment: Is your input device [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) compliant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean "text-only" rather than "headless", since you're apparently looking for interactive input. If using standard input isn't good enough, consider using a `curses` library like [JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/). You could theoretically use the `/dev/eventX` files, but you're going to run into lots of permissions and contention problems, and your program will be 100% non-portable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use the /dev/eventX form, I'm just making this as a personal project for now.  Thank you!

Comment: It'll certainly be a learning experience! Read up on the Linux "event device", and you'll probably be needing some JNI.